# How to use the custom model in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have created a custom Model in MVC where I'm passing 3 tables item as List. and in the view I'm fetching these details. But in View I'm getting `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` 
I'm new to MVC, can anyone help me out please. I don't know where I'm doing wrong!

My MVC Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
   var adminModel = new AdminModel();
   return View(adminModel);
}
```

My Custom Model Code:

```
public class AdminModel
{
    public List<Notification> Notifications { get; set; }            
    public List<Places> Places { get; set; }
}
```

My View Code:

```
@model TravelFly.Models.AdminModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Admin Dashboard";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_AdminPartial.cshtml";
}
<p class="text-danger">@Model.Notifications.Count</p>
... some other contents...
```

Update: 
Controller Code:

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var adminModel = new AdminModel();
            return View(adminModel);
        }
```

Class file:

public List Notifications { get; set; } = new List();
    public List Places { get; set; } = new List();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I was not passing the data to list item I created in the custom Model. So the new controller code will be:

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var adminModel = new AdminModel {

                Notifications = db.Notifications.ToList(),
                Places = db.Places.ToList()

            };
            return View(adminModel);
        }
```

and Custom Model Class file:

```
 public class AdminModel
    {

        public List<Notification> Notifications { get; set; } = new List<Notification>();
        public List<Places> Places { get; set; } = new List<Places>();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should probably initialize the collections on your model or test if is null on view.

```
var adminModel = new AdminModel
{
   Notifications = new List<Notification>(),
   Places = new List<Places>()
};
```

OR

```
@if(Model.Notifications !=null)
{
   <p class="text-danger">@Model.Notifications.Count</p>
}
```

OR

```
public class AdminModel
{
    public List<Notification> Notifications { get; set; }            
    public List<Places> Places { get; set; }

   public AdminModel()
   {
      Notifications = new List<Notification>();
      Places = new List<Places>();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your model isn't being populated before you pass it to the view. You need to call something like this:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var adminModel = new AdminModel();

    adminModel.Notifications = new List<Notifications>();
    // Create a new notification [yourCreatedNotification]... then add it to the list
    adminModel.Notifications.Add(yourCreatedNotification);

     return View(adminModel);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Notifications` doesn't have a default value in your `AdminModel` class, so, when you're sending the new `adminModel` object to your view, that property is `null` and you cant call `.Count` on it.

The solution depends on what you're trying to achieve, but if you want to start by avoiding the exception you could add a default value to the property by initializing it.

```
public class AdminModel
    {
        public List<Notification> Notifications { get; set; } = new List<Notification>()            
        public List<Places> Places { get; set; }
    }
```

If you dont want to change that in your class you could set it's value before sending it to the view:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
   var adminModel = new AdminModel();
   adminModel.Notifications = new List<Notification>();
   return View(adminModel);
}
```

Comment: It solved my problem, but I have 1 data in my Notification Table and in the view its showing `0` value! How to solve this?

Comment: Please share your new code or ask another question with it so we can help you.